# Why does my div expand in Firefox, Chrome, and not Safari?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, zooming

I've got a div that zooms in and out *horizontally* with cmd +/cmd - using Firefox and Chrome (this is good!), but not Safari (not so good!).  The CSS that I use is:

```
 #container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding:0px 25px;
        position:relative;
}

#container:after,  {
    clear:both;
    content:"\0020";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Its working in my system in all browsers, try clearing your cache.

Comment: Ugh...I had my cache disabled and thought that it was cleared, and just noticed that Zoom Text Only was checked.  Noob mistake: I'm just investigating accessibility. Though, I do have a follow up question related to the exact same code: is there anyway to max out the container width so that at some point only the text gets bigger? (I tried max-width but it didn't seem to do anything)  And, I'd be happy to repost if that's more appropriate!

Comment: Do you mean zoom into the DIV till its maximum width of the screen and then stops and continues to zoom the text?

Comment: Exactly!  So, once it hits the end of the screen horizontally, the text will still get bigger, but the container won't increase in width; however, it will increase in height to accommodate the additional text.

Comment: As far as I can tell, zooming is a function of the browser or device you are viewing it on and not CSS. There may be a scripted work around but I doubt it would be possible in pure CSS or HTML. Unfortunately I don't know any scripting.

Comment: That's OK!  I thought that maybe I would in fact need a jquery solution  (which I feel more comfortable width).  Regardless, I was correct in thinking that it was the max-width property?  If so, I can definitely use jquery to check the size of the container and then change the corresponding CSS property.